# Using Camel in existing Spring Boot application with Jetty Server

Tags: java, apache-camel

We have an spring-boot application deployed in embedded jetty server listening on port X. Now I am integrating Apache Camel in this existing application by defining routes. **The goal is to move few rest end points to camel routes that will be proxied to some other service**. I am unable to understand following

- When I use "jetty:http://localhost:Y/myapp" as one of route endpoints. It worked without any error. Does that mean Camel created its own jetty instance ?
- When I use "jetty:http://localhost:X/myapp" - it again worked without giving error that address X is in use

I would like to keep control of jetty server configuration as they were and let camel listen to already existing rest end points.

Comment: You mention "existing REST endpoints": I think you might want to consider directly integrating your existing REST endpoints with Camel, without going down to the servlet level. That's pretty easy to do if you use JAX-RS with Apache CXF as the implementation (check out the CXFRS and CXF Bean components), but you can also use a Camel ProducerTemplate in your existing controller to send a message to a Camel route. It might help if you gave more detail about your use case (e.g. do you want to redirect a broad range of URL paths, or only some specific ones?) and about your existing REST endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Previously our application contacted single backend (say original.com) Now we have extracted some functionality and created micro-service for them. This means original.com/moved-context-path should be redirected to new backend new.com/moved-context-path. We want to deploy using Apache Camel as proxy for selected REST API

Comment: My understanding is that the same application will contain both some REST services implementations (the ones which haven't been extracted so far) and some redirections to external REST services (the new Camel routes). What do you use to expose the remaining REST services? JAX-RS (if yes, is it CXF?), spring-mvc, Restlet, maybe something else? Also, do you want to blindly redirect any path that looks like `original.com/foo/*` or only some specific paths like `original.com/foo/bar1` and `original.com/foo/bar2`?

Comment: Note: I ask all this because I suspect your question is an example of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378): you ask about how to use the Jetty component, but maybe the actual solution is to use another Camel component entirely.

Comment: To answer above question - yes, we would like to blindly redirect original.com/foo/bar1 to new.com/foo/bar and rest of the REST endpoints exposed currently using spring RestController with jetty remain the same

Comment: OK, i'm even more confused now... I used the word "blindly" (maybe not the best choice of word) for the example with a wildcard, you use it with an example with a specific path (and one which needs to be configured specifically too, since you redirect from `/foo/bar1` to `/foo/bar`)... So which one is it you want? Redirect `original/foo/*` to `new/foo/*` indiscriminately, or only target some specific paths for redirection?

Comment: In fact, a maybe better/more accurate question is: are the paths to be redirected nicely segregated from the others, or not? Like, all paths beginning with `/foo/` are redirected, none of them are handled locally (that makes things easier!). Or, on the contrary, `/foo/bar1`and `/foo/bar3` must be redirected, but `/foo/bar2` and `/foo/bar4` are not directed (that's a bit less straightforward, because you can't just configure a Camel-specific servlet mapped to `/foo/*`).

Answer (score 2):

If you can configure a servlet mapping which matches all paths which need to be redirected (for example, paths like `foo/*` are always redirected), then things are pretty easy. If this doesn't work you, I will try to edit my answer later.

The relevant page from the official docs [is here](http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-camel-as-a-http-proxy-between-a-client-and-server.html). The interesting example for you is the one using the [servlet component](http://camel.apache.org/servlet.html), because you already have a servlet container (Jetty) configured and running.

First, need to configure the Camel servlet. It depends on how your existing servlet(s) are configured; for instance, using a web.xml file, add:

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Or, if you are using spring-boot, you can just register the following bean:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
    CamelHttpTransportServlet servlet = new CamelHttpTransportServlet("CamelServlet");
    servlet.setServletName();
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet,"/foo/*");
}
```

Anyway, once you have the Camel servlet registered with your Jetty instance, you can use the servlet component, and redirect everything:

```
from("servlet:foo?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
.to("http4://new.com/foo?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false");
```

- `http4` is the [HTTP4 component](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html), based on Apache HTTPClient 4.x. (you can still use the [HTTP component](http://camel.apache.org/http.html) base on HTTPClient 3.x if you want).
- `matchOnUriPrefix=true` will match wildcards
- `bridgeEndpoint=true` means we are acting as a proxy
- `throwExceptionOnFailure=false` means errors returned by the `new` server will just be relayed to the caller, without being handled by Camel.

A request to `http://old.com/foo/some/crazy/path/i/just/made/up` should be redirected to `http://new.com/foo/some/crazy/path/i/just/made/up` (and likely result in a 404 error from the `new.com` server, which will be simply forwarded to the initial caller).

Answer (score 1):

Camel does not listen to "already existing" endpoints in the way you're expecting; it creates its own using the scheme-indicated component.  You've created a Jetty endpoint (i.e. "jetty:..."), so Camel spins up a Camel Jetty component to handle HTTP requests at that endpoint.

If you want to use Camel as a proxy to redirect (which might be more easily accomplished with a network load balancer), then you'd spin up Camel routes to *replace* the existing endpoints and route them to the new endpoints.
  from("jetty:http://oldendpoint.com")
      .to("jetty:http://newendpoint.com");